# Redirect mysite.com to www.mysite.com with SSL wildcard before security warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I have an SSL wildcard for my rails site through DNSimple, and have deployed to Heroku.
I have smoothly functioning full-site SSL for all subdomains of my site, except for when I enter my site name without a subdomain into a browser for the first time.

Although my Heroku settings redirects `http://mysite.com` to `https://www.mysite.com`, the browser pops up a security warning first, because the SSL certificate for `*mysite.com` requires a subdomain.

Is there a way to redirect from no subdomain to with subdomain before checking for the security certificate?

This is a substantial issue, as it's unreasonable to require/expect first time visitors to type in `www` before the site name.

Comment: I would say that you should be going in the opposite direction and redirecting away from `www.` Personal preference of course, but www feels so... 90s. Established sites like google might have an excuse of identity, but it's not a very good one.

Comment: Thanks @TheZ, do you know if there's a way to do that with a wildcard certificate for `*mysite.com`? I need the wildcard because I have a bunch of subdomains, but would consider removing the `www` from the home page. I agree that `www` is rather 90s, but I'm not sure if there's a way to have both (no subdomain on homepage, and subdomain on other pages, all with SSL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use subdomain redirection: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords#subdomain-redirection

but I think only with the www form, as it warns:

> Requests made directly to naked domains via SSL (i.e.
>   https://mydomain.com) will encounter a warning when using subdomain
>   redirection. This is expected and can be avoided by only circulating
>   and publicizing the subdomain format of your secure URL.

Comment: Hi @tictacbum. That's what I'm currently doing. I guess there's no way around this. I'm surprised this isn't a bigger issue. No one goes around describing their site as "doubleyoudoubleyoudoubleyoumysitedotcom"... This may be a good reason to forgo site-wide SSL...

Comment: I realized I had just forgotten change my ALIAS record for `mysite.com` to point to `mysite.herokussl.com` instead of the old `mysite.herokuapp.com` from when I didn't have SSL. As you mention, a naked domain with `https` will trigger a warning, but that's fine, as long as a bare address with `http` doesn't.